# Unable to fire GA event in jquery

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

```
dp("a.download-2").click(function(){
    
    var e=dp(this).attr("id");
    var t=dp(this).attr("name");
    var n=dp(this).attr("rel");
    var r=navigator.platform;
    var i=r.substring(0,3);

    if(i=="Win"){
        jQuery("#fb_pixel").addClass("fb_conversion");

        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent",n,"download",t]);

        window.location.href="http://"+e+".rackcdn.com/abc123.exe";
    }else if(i=="Mac"){
        jQuery("#fb_pixel").addClass("fb_conversion");

        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent",n,"download",t]);

        window.location.href="http://"+e+".rackcdn.com/abc123.dmg";
        
    }else{
        alert("The software only supports Windows and Mac operating system.");return false}});
```

the tracking in this code will not work.

but if i add in one alert code below the GA tracking event code. the tracking works fine. like the code below,

```
dp("a.download-2").click(function(){
    
    var e=dp(this).attr("id");
    var t=dp(this).attr("name");
    var n=dp(this).attr("rel");
    var r=navigator.platform;
    var i=r.substring(0,3);

    if(i=="Win"){
        jQuery("#fb_pixel").addClass("fb_conversion");

        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent",n,"download",t]);
        alert(n+" "+t);

        window.location.href="http://"+e+".rackcdn.com/abc123.exe";
    }else if(i=="Mac"){
        jQuery("#fb_pixel").addClass("fb_conversion");

        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent",n,"download",t]);
        alert(n+" "+t);

        window.location.href="http://"+e+".rackcdn.com/abc123.dmg";
        
    }else{
        alert("The software only supports Windows and Mac operating system.");return false}});
```

I've no idea why this alert is affecting. by right it shouldn't.

Comment: it looks like the redirect is triggered before GA has a chance to sent the request... so try to use something like `setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://"+e+".rackcdn.com/abc123.dmg";}, 50)`

Answer (score 1):

The line `window.location.href="http://"+e+".rackcdn.com/abc123.exe";` forces the browser to redirect before your GA code has had a chance to work.

So you can try using a `setTimeout` within your code after the GA code is written. That way you can ensure that the GA code runs prior to redirecting the page.

The `alert` works because it pauses execution till you click 'OK', which is enough time in the world for any javascript to work before it.

Comment: exactly like what Arun proposed. setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://"+e+".rackcdn.com/abc123.dmg‌​";}, 50); it's working now.

Comment: Right. He beat me to it :)